# ASIFormDataRequest: unable to send file to server using asynchronous request

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, synchronous, asiformdatarequest

I would like to send a file asynchronously to the server; however, it seems like when I do send the request to the server. The server gives me a HTTP code: 200, which is OK but no file is being uploaded to the server.

However, when I leave it to synchronous... it works perfectly. Weird..

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated,

```
- (void) sendCSVtoServer: ( Session * ) archive_session {

    NSLog(@"file name: %@", [archive_session getFile]);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:3000/xxx/xxxxxxxx"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setPostValue: [archive_session getEmail] forKey:@"email"];
    [request addFile: [archive_session getFile] forKey:@"csv"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What gets printed in your `NSLog`? Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: @MikeD: Yes, files do exist.

Comment: Did you implement `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate`?

Comment: @MikeD: Nope! What you see is all I have implemented, just using the premade methods

Comment: @MikeD: it is also a ASIFormDataRequest... does that make a different?

Comment: Yes. `ASIFormDataRequest` is a subclass of `ASIHTTPRequest`.

Comment: Just a FYI, but you might want to think of getting away from ASIHttpRequest and switch to another library (ASI is no longer being developed).  I switched to AFNetworking and love it.  Much cleaner (uses blocks instead of delegates) and faster.  Even the developer of ASI has told people to move away from ASI.  If you need an example of doing this same thing using AFNetworking, let me know.  I have a complete NetworkClient class written as a wrapper for AFN.

Comment: @ElJay: An example would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @ELJay: just worked on it on my own... thanks ElJay! AFNetworking worked for me! :)

Comment: Sorry - was away from a computer for awhile.  If you would like an example of how I work with AFN, I can post as an answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: hey, no problem. I got it working! thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a delegate, but you mention you did not implement any of those methods. `ASIFormDataRequest` extends `ASIHTTPResquest`, and therefore inherits all its properties.

You will have to implement methods decalred in `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate`, at least

`- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;`

and

`- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;`

Maybe others depending on your needs.

Your upload is probably still working (can you check your server?), but, when you send the request asynchronously, you don't have any way to determine if the request has succeeded or failed; right now you are just sedning and forgetting.

All the methods declared in `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h` are marked as optional, which is why the debugger, compiler, and runtime is not complaining.

Comment: My upload is working but there is no content in the files for some odd reason.

Comment: @freedom If all the information is indicating your file has been uploaded successfully, then maybe it is not your client side code that is the propblem. What do the server logs say?

Comment: oddly, i used AFNetworking (objective c library) and used the same server side code and it seems to be working. :/

but before, the server logs said it was successful

thanks for the help!

Comment: @freedom Out for curiousity, what version of iOS are you targeting?